# what does the definite integral of a parametrised integral look like?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Say we have an integral $\tfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\tfrac{1}{z-a}dz$

I know this can be parametrised as

$$\tfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int^1_0\tfrac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}dt$$.

My question :

So long as $a\notin \{\gamma\}$ is it true that

$$\tfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int^1_0\tfrac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}dt=\tfrac{1}{2\pi i}[F(1)-F(0)]$$(as the integrand is holomorphic)

and also what doesthe expression for F(1) look like ?

Comment: What is $F{}{}$?

Comment: As a specific example say that $\gamma=a+e^{2\pi it}.$ Then $\int_0^1\tfrac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt=\int_0^12\pi i dt$. So for this example $F(1)=2\pi i$. My question is what does the expression for F look like in general ?

Comment: Id's say: $$\int^1_0\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}dt=\int^{\gamma(1)}_{\gamma(0)}\frac{d \gamma}{\gamma-a}=$$ $$=\int^{\gamma(1)-a}_{\gamma(0)-a}\frac{d s}{s}=\ln (\gamma(1)-a)-\ln (\gamma(0)-a)$$

Provided $\gamma(t)$ is monotone and $\gamma(t) \neq a$ for $t \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to show is that $\int_0^0.5\tfrac{\gamma'(2t)}{\gamma(2t)-a}dt+\int_0.5^1\tfrac{\\sigma'(2t-1)}{\sigma(2t-1)-a}dt=\int_0^1\tfrac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}dt+\int_0^1\tfrac{\sigma'(t)}{\sigma(t)-a}dt$. where $\gamma(1)=\sigma(0)$. and I want a way to express this